# TeamCity failed to connect MySQL which is run in Docker

Tags: mysql, teamcity

I start MySQL in docker by using below command:

```bash
docker run --name mysql-for-teamcity \

-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=FAKE-ROOT-PW\

-v ~/MySQL/var_lib_mysql:/var/lib/mysql \

-p 3306:3306 \

-p 33060:33060 \

-it mysql
```

But TeamCity failed to connect the MySQL, the error message is :
[image]

I can connect to the MySQL in Terminal using below command:

```bash
mysql -u root --protocol=tcp -p
```

And database "teamcity" has also been created.

My Environment:

- Mac OS X 10.14.1
- Docker Desktop 2.0.0.0-mac81(29211)
- TeamCity and MySQL are running in seperated Docker containers
- Both Docker images tag is latest

Comment: Does Team City is running on the same machine where you are running the terminal?

Comment: @daggett Both TeamCity and MySQL are running in Docker containers, and both containers are running on my Mac. You remind me, I did not configure port forward from TeamCity Container to MySQL container. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The reason is TeamCity and MySQL are running in the separate containers, so when I specified "127.0.0.1" for TeamCity, it is not possible for it to connect to MySQL. Because they are simply not running in the same host.

The solution is using Docker Compose which set up a local network for containers by default.

Step 1: create a **docker-compose.yml** in an empty directory you want to place your TeamCity:

```
version: '3'
services:
  TeamCity:
    image: jetbrains/teamcity-server
    ports:
     - "8111:8111"
    volumes:
     - <your TeamCity dir>/data:/data/teamcity_server/datadir
     - <your TeamCity dir>log:/opt/teamcity/logs
  MySQL:
    image: mysql
    ports:
     - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
     - <your TeamCity dir>/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - mysql.env
```

Step 2: create a **mysql.env** in the same directory:

```bash
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=YOUR-MYSQL-PASSWD
```

Step 3: run `docker-compose up -d` in the terminal in

Step 4: open "http://127.0.0.1:8111" in browser

Step 5: input "MySQL:3306" in the DataBase Host field.